# Prove the $p$-norm is indeed a norm

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that $\|x\|_p=\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\, |x_j|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ is a norm for $1<p<\infty$.

It is trivial that $\|0\|_p=0$ and $\|x\|_p>0$ for $x\ne0$, s well as $\|kx\|_p=|k|\cdot\|x\|_p$ for $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now I am trying to prove that $\|x+y\|_p\le \|x\|_p+\|y\|_p$.  I am trying to get $$\|x+y\|_p^p = (\|x\|_p+\|y\|_p)\frac{\|x+y\|_p^p}{||x+y||_p } $$

Here is the progress I have made, but I do not know where to go from here:

$$\|x+y\|_p^p = \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j+y_j|^p \le \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j+y_j|^{p-1}|x_j|+\sum_{j=1}^n |x_j+y_j|^{p-1}|y_j|.$$

Can someone give me any input?

Comment: What is $p$? For $p\in(0,1)$, this is actually not true.. (for the others: [Minkowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) is a good keyword).

Comment: I apologize, I will edit this $1<p<\infty$

Comment: Are you familiar with Holder's inequality? You have $|x+y|^p=|x+y||x+y|^{p-1} \leq |x||x+y|^{p-1} + |y||x+y|^{p-1}$. Show that $|x+y|^{p-1}$ is in $L^q$ where $\frac{1}{p}+{1}{q}=1$ (that is, $\left(\sum_{j=1}^n (|x_j+y_j|^{p-1})^q\right)^\frac{1}{q}<\infty$), and apply Holder's inequality to $|x|$ and $|x+y|^{p-1}$, as well as to $|y|$ and $|x+y|^{p-1}$. You should wind up with what you're trying to get.